# C language: write to file without buffering

Tags: c, output-buffering, printf

I have opened a file for writing some data to a file, but it keeps buffering and won't write anything to the file until the program ends. How can I skip the buffering process and write directly to the file.

My code:

```
fprintf (fp, "# Step: %d  %f\n", ntot, eDiff);
for(i=0; i<nType; i++)  
    fprintf (fp, "%s  %f %f\n",param[i].cTypes, param[i].eps, param[i].sigma);
fprintf(fp, "#  ============\n");
```

Comment: It may be the OS that is buffering in some weird way, if there is any buffering at all. There is something that may help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: You're missing the fopen, fsync, and fclose calls. You're even missing main(). How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: use `setvbuf` buffering control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fflush() function on the stream:

```
fflush( fp );
```

Comment: Or you can use `setbuf(fp, NULL);`